# Drool Workbench : Not display all classes for Import in Guided Rule Config Tab

Tags: java, drools

Right now i am trying to do some POC with JBoss Drool Workbench.

I am facing one Problem: I have uploaded on JAR file as a dependency. which contains Bean and some of the business logic service class. which also contains class which have list of static method which need to call from Rule.

My Problem is i am able to get all beans and constant classes in Guided Rule UI in Config tab for Imports. but other then all remaining class, like class contains  static method are not available for import. Due to that i am not able to import that class, and not able to use that one.

Please help me out.

Genius Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seen warning i came to know that i also need to upload dependent jar file in workbench and also provide dependency to project, drool itself provide a hint for same. finally the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In the project setting tab, you have to add dependency of the maven project containing POJO. It will give you option to either load from central or load from local repository. If you choose, central, the pom.xml will contain the reference to download the dependency while createing the jar. If you choose from local, it will add the class files to your jar.